# C++ better way to handle function overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

I have code like:

```
void Foo(int& a, string& b, vector<int>& c) {
... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
... // 10 lines of code to parse and assign value to vector<int>& c
}

void Foo(int& a, string& b, map<string, int>& d) {
... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
... // 10 lines of code to parse and assign value to map<string, int>& d
}
```

Is there any way to avoid repeat that 30 lines of code? Should I use function overloading in this case?

**EDIT:**

What if the code is not easy to separate out? Like:

```
void Foo(int& a, string& b, vector<int>& c) {
  for() {
    if(m) ... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
    else if(n) ... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
    else if(o) ... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
    else if(p) ... // 10 lines of 'vector<int>& c' code
    else if(q) ... // 10 lines of 'vector<int>& c' code
  }
}


void Foo(int& a, string& b, map<string, int>& d) {
  for() {
    if(m) ... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
    else if(n) ... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
    else if(o) ... // 30 lines of code are same as another function
    else if(p) ... // 10 lines of 'map<string, int>& d' code
    else if(q) ... // 10 lines of 'map<string, int>& d' code
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put common 30 lines in a separate function?

Comment: Put the 30 lines of common code in a separate function, that is called by both the `Foo` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could factor out the common code:

```
void helper(int& a, string& b) { 
  ... // 30 lines of common code
}
```

then use that in the functions:

```
void Foo(int& a, string& b, vector<int>& c) {     
  helper(a, b);
  ... // 10 lines of code to parse and assign value to vector<int>& c     
}     

void Foo(int& a, string& b, map<string, int>& d) {     
   helper(a, b);
.  .. // 10 lines of code to parse and assign value to map<string, int>& d     
}
```

Alternatively, you could use templates if the common code contains references to the containers as well:

```
template<template<typename T, typename Alloc> class Container>
void helper(int& a, string& b, Container& d) { 
  ... // 30 lines of common code
}
```

Note: You will have to use template specialization as not all containers have the same insertion (or access) method (e.g. vector, list: `push_back`; map: `insert`)

UPDATE: after OP added more code to question:

If the only difference is in the handling of the containers, but the "spirit" of the container handling is very similar, you could create (template) wrappers for the containers and pass the wrapper into a common function: the differences will be captured in the different implementations of the wrappers.

Answer (score 6):

Refactor the 30 lines into a helper function you call in both overloads.

Edit: If the code is different enough that you're struggling to separate it, then what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps most of the common stuff can be handled with iterators?